# Tracing operations in Mongodb Bulk Operation

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.6.1. The question from me is that-
"Is it possible for keep a track of _id in Bulk Operations??"
Suppose if I have created one object for BulkWriteOperation, for example 50 documents to be inserted to the 'B' collection from 'A' collection. I need ***keep a list of successful write operations and failed write operations*** also.

Bulk Inserts and deletes are working fine. But the question is that-
-- "I need to keep a track of _ids, **for a query- find the documents from A** and **insert to B collection**. In the mean while, I need to keep a list of _ids (successful and failed operations). **I need to delete the documents in A collection, only for those successful operations and keep failed documents as it is**"--

Please help me out.

Thanking you :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to use `UnorderedBulkOperation` for the entire batch to execute. You will need to use a try/catch around your `BulkWriteOperation.execute()`, catching [BulkWriteException](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteException.html) which will give you access to a list of [BulkWriteError](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteError.html) as well as the [BulkWriteResult](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteResult.html).

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
MongoClient m = new MongoClient("localhost");
DB db = m.getDB( "test" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection( "bulk" );
coll.drop();
coll.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("i", 1), new BasicDBObject("unique", true));

BulkWriteOperation bulkWrite = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    bulkWrite.insert(new BasicDBObject("i", i));
}
// Now add 10 documents to the batch that will generate a unique index error
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bulkWrite.insert(new BasicDBObject("i", i));
}

BulkWriteResult result = null;
List<BulkWriteError> errors = null;
try {
    result = bulkWrite.execute();
} catch (BulkWriteException bwe) {
    bwe.printStackTrace();
    errors = bwe.getWriteErrors();
    result = bwe.getWriteResult();
}

for (BulkWriteError e : errors) {
    System.out.println(e.getIndex() + " failed");
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thank you.. Is it not possible for getting the ObjectIds of all the successful operations and failed operations??

Comment: Not currently as best I can tell. It looks like you will need to maintain your own list of the inserts and use the index of the errors to determine what has failed. You can explicitly assign your ObjectIds so that you know what the ids are of the successful operations.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.. Could you please give me some information about addressing SQL injection in Mongodb..